# Merging cmdlet outputs

Tags: powershell, certutil

I've been trying to solve this problem for a while but can't seem to find a decent solution.
I'm pulling the output of two certutil commands inside of a Powershell script:

```
certutil -View -config $CAserver -restrict "Disposition=20" csv >> $output1
certutil -View -config $CAserver -restrict "Disposition=16" csv >> $output2
```

Problem is that I'm getting the headers for each disposition individually even if do this as a one-liner with "Disposition>=16,Disposition<=20" and it's breaking things further down the line. I'm looking for a way to take the values from one command and append it to the csv of the other.

Current output:

```
"HeaderA1","HeaderA2","HeaderA3","HeaderA4"
"ValueA1","ValueA2","ValueA3","ValueA4"
"HeaderB1","HeaderB2","HeaderB3","HeaderB4"
"ValueB1","ValueB2","ValueB3","ValueB4"
```

Desired output:

```
"HeaderA1","HeaderA2","HeaderA3","HeaderA4"
"ValueA1","ValueA2","ValueA3","ValueA4"
"ValueB1","ValueB2","ValueB3","ValueB4"
```

Example code to interpret the outputs:

```
$import = Import-Csv $output | Where-Object { ($_. "Certificate Template" -eq <TEMPLATE_STRING>) -OR ($_. "Request Disposition" -match <DISPOSITION_STRING>) } | Select-Object 'Issued Common Name','Certificate Effective Date','Certificate Expiration Date','Certificate Template','Serial Number'
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Can you show us the contents of `$output1` and `$output2` produced by your `certutil` calls; some PowerShell code you've tried parsing `$output1` and `$output2`; and also the expected output result?

Comment: I'll add it to my question

Comment: cmdlets are powershell commands written in c#.  You can skip the first line of output in the second command.